# What are microsoft excel alternatives for editing .xlsx formats which are free of cost?

Tags: excel, xlsx

Open office does not support .xlsx format.I found [this](http://www.kingsoftstore.com/spreadsheets-free.html) which is good as it very compatible to excel but it still does not support editing .xlsx format(the free versions of it).

Is there any way to get around.

Comment: The last version of [*LibreOffice*](http://www.libreoffice.org/features/calc/) do support xlsx files.

Comment: Try Kingsoft Office: http://www.ksosoft.com/product/compare. The free version should read and edit xlsx, but may not be able to export it to xlsx.

Comment: @LJ - That's the s/w that OP says he's found, but free versions __don't__ support editing

Comment: Kings Office pro will let me do it (edit .xlsx) i dont know about Libre office

Comment: Open and Libre Office have supported read/edit/write of MS Office BIFF and OfficeOpenXML format files for quite some time now (since version 3.0, which was released in 2008 - that's 5 years of support for xlsx)

Comment: Gnumeric works well with MS Excel BIFF and OfficeOpenXML spreadsheet files

Comment: @munish - why do you think Open Office doesn't support xlsx format?

Comment: Hmm sorry i mean it can't save it as .xlsx

Comment: Open Office 4 has very limited saving options for xlsx; but Libre Office allows it without any problems (part of the reason I switched to Libre Office); and Gnumeric is another excellent Spreadsheet program that can read and write xlsx.... and (despite its gnu heritage) runs on most platforms

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [Google Docs](http://docs.google.com) if you wanted to use the cloud.

It's supported [xlsx since 2009](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/T1H54NI6TsQ)

> A new version of Google Spreadsheets is here! Make sure to check out the following features:
>
> XLSX import.  Excel '07 files (xlsx) can now be successfully imported into Google spreadsheets, supporting cell data, formatting, formulas, font style, background color, named ranges, frozen panes, and horizontal merges. Note: there's currently no option to export files as .xlsx.

<strike>Just note that last line about exporting them though.</strike>

---

**Important edit**

I've just checked, exporting as ".xlsx" is now supported via the "Download as" button

[image: Download as xlsx]

Comment: Is there a setting to preserve the original character encoding? I think Google Spreadsheets always export files using `UTF-8`.